# Weird application state after submitting job application

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

This is what I've been running into recently after submitting a job application.

Users can recover by hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> or by reloading the document.

[image: Bug preview]

Comment: While I understand privacy concerns, the lack of context on the web page makes it somewhat difficult to tell what you're looking at...

Comment: @Emrakul, the obfuscated job content was displayed correctly. Perhaps it's the added weirdness of the overlay which lacked any content, except for the Careers logo. If I find the chance, I'll try to reproduce and document from a different platform, without any additional client extensions.

Comment: @Emrakul there you go

Comment: Thanks for reporting! We've been working in this area recently and it seems some of our changes leaked out inadvertently. We'll get a fix out shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now - thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure, thank you (y)!